# How can I plot a multi-class confusion matrix?

Tags: python

I am trying to plot a confusion matrix for my topic classification. However, when I plot it, I can't see anything clearly. I get scribbled X and Y axis without anything properly plotted. How can I plot it in a better way to see how my documents are being classified? I have 22465 documents and 88 topics.

Here is my code:

```
from pandas_confusion import ConfusionMatrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
model = LogisticRegression()
model = model.fit(matrix_tmp, label_tmp)
pred = model.predict(matrix_tmp_test)

print(metrics.accuracy_score(label_tmp_test,pred))
print(metrics.classification_report(label_tmp_test,pred))

cm=ConfusionMatrix(label_tmp_test,pred)
print(cm)
cm.plot()
plt.show()
```

This is the plot I receive.
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to plot a confusion matrix with 90 classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35272823/is-it-possible-to-plot-a-confusion-matrix-with-90-classes)

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer,
Hi, 
[PyCM](https://github.com/sepandhaghighi/pycm) is a python module which can help you to show a multi-class confusion matrix through different types of reports such as a html report and also plotting it.

There is a simple code for saving a html report of a confusion matrix.

```
cm.save_html("file_name",color=(R,G,B))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by the code blow:

```
from torch import randint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import seaborn as sn
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

cf_matrix = confusion_matrix(randint(5, (20,)), randint(5, (20,)))
CLASSES = [1,2,3,4,5]
df_cm = pd.DataFrame(cf_matrix / np.sum(cf_matrix, axis=1)[:, None], index = [i for i in CLASSES], columns = [i for i in CLASSES])
plt.figure(figsize = (12,7))
sn.heatmap(df_cm, annot=True)
plt.savefig("output1.png")
```

please note that at this line;

```
cf_matrix = confusion_matrix(randint(5, (20,)), randint(5, (20,)))
```

The first parameter of **confusion_matrix** is True Boxes and the second parameter is Pred Boxes

[image]