# ConfusionMatrix size to be enlarged

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, scikit-learn, visualization, confusion-matrix

I have a confusion matrix,But I want to increase its scale along x-axis and y-axis for better reading.
for plotting confusion matrix, I am using sklearn confusion matrix.
**Since the class labels are around 20, so I want to increase the size.
These options not working  **AS THEY ONLY INCREASE THE SIZE OF THE FIGURE AND NOT THE PLOTTED CONFUSION MATRIX INSIDE IT**

```
fig, ax = pplt.subplots()#pplt.subplot(111)
fig.set_size_inches(25.5, 15, forward=True)
```

---

[image: cnfusion matrix from sklearn library]

Comment: If usual ways to change the figure size are not working, you need to provide a [mcve] and allow people to reproduce the problem.

Comment: The solution you referred to only increases figure size!!! Not the size of the plotted confusion matrix inside it :(

Comment: That is unfortunate, but not reproducible. See first comment.

Comment: Could you generally tell, how to plot readable confusion matrix for around 90 classes. I know there are other similar questions like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35272823/is-it-possible-to-plot-a-confusion-matrix-with-90-classes but they dont answer my question.